# redirect to index.html.var

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

My default webserver is Apache, I have installed node on my account and installed Ghost platform. Node runs on a specific port hence I have created a .htaccess file to redirect all requests from port 80 to the port where Node is installed.

The problem is that on one server the redirect works perfectly while on another server the homepage redirects to index.html.var
What could be the issue ? Below is the code of my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

IndexIgnore *

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

# Simple URL redirect:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com:6366/$1 [P]

</IfModule>
```

Please let me know what am I missing.

Comment: Can you check if `$1` (maybe index.html) actually exists on the faulty server ?

Comment: No the index.html does not exist. There is only index.js where it should be redirected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding 
DirectoryIndex
to the .htaccess file.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This answer works for node expressjs app too ! thank you

Comment: How did you do it. I mean the actual codes in .htaccess